# Error:Cannot Compile Script (PineScript Web)

Tags: save, pine-script

PineScriptv5 Web compiler(Firefox,Chrome.......Windows10) is giving a compile error whenever the editor is **started for the first time**.

It does show the saved custom code from the previous session ,***but it does not show the code's saved 'LAST'revision[1,2,..,18,19,LAST]*** from the previous session and shows only the first 1 or 2 revisions.

Even deleting the Indicator from the Chart still gives the above Error.
The Internet is working  and Scripts from the Public Library load and run fine.

1. How to make PineScript show the LAST revision of the previous sessions saved script?
2. Does the script get saved on disk (to prevent from losing work on previous sessions code)?

***ERROR***

```
 Error:Cannot Compile Script
```

[image]

[image: image2]

Comment: This is not normal editor behaviour, you should contact the help desk for this type of issue https://www.tradingview.com/support/tickets/

Comment: 1. By saving minor versions (e.g 2.1) which applied on the chart you will be able to open it (as v3) in the other layout from your saved scripts menu. Otherwise, when going to the new chart layout that unsaved versions will be unavailable.  

2. Yes. 

If you would provide more complete info about the steps how you saving your scripts and layouts we could help you with this error.

Comment: The previous versions 18,19,LastVersion were saved using the 'SAVE' button provided on the Top-Right corner(next to OPEN) in the PineEditor......Is there a way to directly save the script on disk?

Comment: > `Is there a way to directly save the script on disk?`

Only by copy-pasting it in your local text editor.

Comment: Which  LOCAL TEXT EDITOR is recommended considering that it has to come with  AUTOCOMPLETE supported Plugins for PineScriptv5 and automatic execution from disk?

Comment: For now community editors available for V4 only. 
https://www.pinecoders.com/resources/#text-editor-highlighters-and-utilities-for-pine
For local saving purposes you can use Notepad++.